# Start datepicker from assined EditText

Tags: android, datepicker

I have Button with date in it

[image: image 1]

when I click it, datepicker dialog shows up but start with current date

[image: image 2]

how I start datepicker dialog with the date that I've set in my Button

here is my code

```
date_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Dialog.Builder builder = null;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 10;
        c.set(year, c.get(Calendar.MONTH), c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        builder = new com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog.Builder(R.style.CustomStyle_DatePicker) {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog dialog = (com.rey.material.app.DatePickerDialog) fragment.getDialog();
                String date = dialog.getFormattedDate(SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance());
                date_btn.setText(date);
                selectedDate.set(dialog.getYear(), dialog.getMonth(), dialog.getDay());
                super.onPositiveActionClicked(fragment);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNegativeActionClicked(DialogFragment fragment) {
                super.onNegativeActionClicked(fragment);
            }
        }.dateRange(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000, c.getTimeInMillis()).date(selectedDate.get(Calendar.DATE),
                selectedDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                , selectedDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        builder.positiveAction("OK")
                .negativeAction("CANCEL");
        DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(builder);

        fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);

    }
});
```

I've declare this in public

```
Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Comment: where is the editText ? you mean the button ? if so how u assign the value to button

Comment: sorry, I mean Button...I passing value between activity, so I setText my button (String getDate = extras.getStringExtra("datevalue");) with date_btn.setText(getDate);

Comment: what is the datevalue format

Comment: Mar 31, 2016 so if I'm not mistaken MMM dd, yyyy

Comment: how do you set it to button ??

Comment: i see you do date_btn.setText(getDate) so  
Mar 31, 2016 will be displayed in button?

Comment: so I have this datepicker in MainActivity and set it to button (selected_date.setText(date) from my previous code), and I pass it via intent (intent.putExtra("datevalue", selected_date);) to another activity, call it Activity2...in Activity2 there is another datepicker in case user don't want to go back to MainActivity just to change the date. in Activity2 I set button text with the code from my previous comment above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106987/discussion-between-dhina-and-meeftah).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In intent instead of string add the Calender object itself like below..

```
intent.putExtra("ambiltgl", selectedDate);
```

in other activity get the extra :

```
Intent extras = getIntent(); 
Calendar selectedDateFromPrevActivity= (Calendar) extras.getExtras().get("ambiltgl");
```

And as like earlier set it to datepicker..

```
.date(selectedDateFromPrevActivity.get(Calendar.DATE),
                        selectedDateFromPrevActivity.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                        , selectedDateFromPrevActivity.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```